# Make a table of changes in US coinage

Tags: list-manipulation, date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries

I thought of an innovative use of Mathematica/Alpha that I think Stephen Wolfram would really love, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. The idea is to make a table that would chart the changes in US coinage over time pictorially.

So, the rows would be time periods, and the columns would be denominations (penny, nickel, dime, quarter, half dollar, dollar, possibly eagle and double eagle). So, for example, I think  the coinage did not change from 1921 (when the Peace Dollar was first issued) to 1932 (when the Washington Quarter was adopted). So, that would be one row in the table, 1921-1932 and each cell in that row would show the coin from that period.

I tried using Wolfram Alpha to get the coin images but it was hard. For example, "Washington Quarter" just returns information about the quarter fraction, not the coin.

How  can I go about making an expression/module that will build this table?

Comment: How do you envision handling multiplicity? In some years certain denominations (e.g., quarters) had many commemorative variations.

Comment: Encyclopedic precision is not necessary, just looking to have a table of the main circulating coins.